# Is there a way to limit the verbs allowed by the TFS 2015 REST API?

Tags: tfs

Is it possible to allow only GET requests via the TFS 2015 REST API but still allow normal functionality through the Web interface and via Visual Studio?

### More information:

Authentication and authorization are via Active Directory accounts, but we want to limit the operations that can be performed via the REST API only to retrieving, not changing, TFS data. A vendor has requested that we expose the REST API over the Internet, but management is reluctant unless it can be limited in this way. It may very well not be possible -- at least, my research has so far failed to turn up a solution -- but I want the opinions of people more experienced with TFS than myself.

Comment: This seems like an XY problem. Are you sure you want to do authorization based on HTTP verbs?

Comment: Authentication and authorization are via Active Directory accounts, but we want to limit the operations that can be performed via the REST API only to retrieving, not changing, TFS data. A vendor has requested that we expose the REST API over the Internet, but management is reluctant unless it can be limited in this way. It may very well not be possible -- at least, my research has so far failed to turn up a solution -- but I want the opinions of people more experienced with TFS than myself.

Comment: Ok, please [edit] that additional information into your question. About the question itself, a proxy server which filters the verbs may be an option?

Comment: Thanks, done. I will explore the proxy server idea with our middleware team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No， this can't be achieved for Rest API. Seems you are searching for some settings  or api just like a private permission only work for rest api and not effect web portal or visual studio.

Unless forbidden the related permissions of all area in TFS such as Tore suggested. For example: If the user can't change things through rest api and he should also can't do the same operation in web portal and VS.

Answer (score 1):

The permissions are the same whether you connect through Visual Studio, the web interface, the REST API or any other client. So if the user is only part of the READERS group it can only retrieve whereas being a member of the CONTRIBUTORS group will allow you to change things.